# Solved: whatismyip.net shows ipv6 for my w10 box but ipv4 for my w7 box behind the same router

Tags: proxy, ipv6, ipv4

I am located in Germany but the ipv6 address is from California.
I suppose there is some proxy active as I have played with kaspersky and hotspot shield recently.
I have disabled both of them though and I cannot find any process responsible for the ipv6.
Any clues how I can troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: See the proxy settings in internet control panel i.e. `inetcpl.cpl`

Comment: If you suspect a proxy setting then what is your OS proxy settings set to?  Update your question.  You should also indicate what OS you are using.

Comment: My proxy is set to automatic and if I disable that I get an ipv4 address but that is just a workaround as I want to find out which program did the change. According to OS it as indicated in the topic windows 10 and windows 7 both 64bit.

Comment: It would be nice if you add an answer with the solution instead of changing the title ...

Answer (score 0):

With some trial and error I found that it was in fact a leftover from hotspot shield which intercepted.
I reinstalled and uninstalled it and after a reboot the IP now gets shown as expected.